# core kernel pattern %e on Linux appends PID

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, coredump

According to documentation of [core](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) the %e in kernel pattern stands for  'The process or thread's comm value'. in addition the core comm value is [defined](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) as whatever /proc/[pid]/comm returns. However on my machine (CentOs) despite the kernel pattern is defined  as core-%e and comm value returns only process name, PID is still appended to the core name. Why is this discrepancy between the documentation and actual behaviour?

```
[root@mde-segment-bouretskey dump]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/tmp/dump/core-%e
[root@mde-segment-bouretskey dump]# ls /tmp/dump/core-*
/tmp/dump/core-a.out.42098  /tmp/dump/core-a.out.43097
[root@mde-segment-bouretskey dump]#

[root@mde-segment-bouretskey crashtest]# cat /proc/45301/comm
a.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `kernel.core_uses_pid=0` to avoid having the pid appended when `%p` is missing.

From core(5):

> For backward compatibility, if /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern does not include %p and /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid (see below) is nonzero, then .PID will be appended to the core filename.

Comment: Yep that was that